# LinAlgError("Singular matrix") with statsmodels logistic regression

Tags: python, matrix, statistics, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I'm looking for associations between each predictor in a set of predictors x and each dependent variable in a set of outcomes y corrected for a set of covariates using univariate logistic regression models with `statsmodels` in Python (N=153). Each predictor in x is a continuous variable. The covariates are BMI (as a continuous variable), sex, and age.

For some combinations of x and y, I get the error: `LinAlgError("Singular matrix")`.

**Potential Causes**:

**Highly Correlated Predictors**: Highly correlated predictors, however, this can't be the problem since the same input variables work with other values of y.

**Columns with Only One Value**: Columns consisting of only one value could cause singular matrices, but this is not the case in my predictors, covariates or y variables.

**Low Variance in Dependent Variables**: Both 0 and 1 are present in at least 15% of the sample for all instances of y, so this is likely not the problem.

Perfect Separation: Perfect separation leads to a different error message with `statsmodels` (`PerfectSeparationError: Perfect separation detected, results not available`), and I don't expect perfect separation in my dataset.

**Different Solver**: I've also read that switching to a different logistic regression with a different solver might be necessary, though I don't think changing the solver is possible in `statsmodels`, and I've struggled to find other implementations of logistic regression in Python other than `sklearn`'s (not suitable for my application).

What might be a solution to my problem?

Example code:

```
for y in Y:
    for x in X_df.columns:
        X = Covariates
        X[x] = X_df[x]
        X = sm.add_constant(X)
        model = sm.Logit(y, X)
        result = model.fit()
        
# Y.iloc[:, 0] = works fine 
# Y.iloc[:, 1] = works fine 
# Y.iloc[:, 2] = LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
```

Comment: `Both 0 and 1 are present in at least 15% of the sample for all instances of y`

I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean "In at least 15% of instances of a given value of y, there are both 0 and 1 in predictor variables", then this does not necessarily solve low variance in dependent variables. It may be the case that one of your variables has, say, 152 entries equal to 0 and 1 entry equal to 1. Check the distribution of each predictor variable. If the distributions are highly skewed, this may be the cause of the issue.

Comment: `Highly Correlated Predictors: Highly correlated predictors, however, this can't be the problem since the same input variables work with other values of y.` So the problem seems to be your target variable (y). Take a look at its distribution to see if it is too skewed.

Comment: @Lfppfs My apologies if I didn't make this clear enough in the question. I mean that both 0 and 1 are present in at least 15% of the samples in each entry of y. So 152 entries of 0 and 1 of 1 would be impossible. The minimum either can have is 153*0.15 since I exclude entries for y which do not satisfy this. I think this also answers your second comment.

Comment: `I mean that both 0 and 1 are present in at least 15% of the samples in each entry of y` ok, I think I understand what you mean now. Still, the issue may not be in your y variable, it may be in your predictor variables (X). You mentioned `Columns with Only One Value`, but it does not necessarily need to be a single value. If the distribution of one of these variables is highly skewed, you may end up with a singular matrix. Therefore, check the distribution of each X. You could try plotting a scatterplot matrix.

Comment: changing the solver in statsmodels means using `model.fit(method="xxx")` e.g. "bfgs" or "nm", Almost all solvers use scipy.optimize.

Comment: @Josef I think this might be a good option. I will try it, thanks Josef!